# Set shipping address in paypal chained payments

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to setup chained payments and here is what I do:

- Call the `Pay` API using `CREATE`
- After receiving the paykey, I make the `setPaymentOptions` API to set up `senderOptions` where I set the shipping address.
- However, when I try to `getShippingAddresses`, I just see an incoherent message come up, with no shipping addresses specified:

  { responseEnvelope: 
  { timestamp: '2015-08-21T17:59:52.683-07:00',
   ack: 'Success',
   correlationId: 'eb86130f0d7a3',
   build: '17820627' },
  httpStatusCode: 200 }

How do I set the shipping address in chained payments? The missing shipping address results in the transaction missing out on `Seller Protection`. Please help.

Comment: Have you completed the checkout after calling Pay with CREATE and following that up with SetPaymentOptions?  If you complete the payment you should see the shipping address included in the PayPal transaction details.

Comment: I had tried completing the checkout. But the sandbox kept giving me an error - "Message 3005 - We are sorry, we are experiencing temporary difficulties. Please try again later". And this error has been there for more than a month now.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache/cookies, or even using a separate clean browser that you don't normally use.  The sandbox can have issues with that sometimes.

Comment: I have tried doing that. Tried using different browsers, but it still does not work!